# How can i set height and width prop from image on xamarin.forms?

Tags: image, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
<Grid Column="0" Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource DashboardMenusMyProfileGridStyle}">

       <Image Source="myEvent.png" WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16"></Image>
       <Label Text="Hesabım" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
    </Grid>
```

Hello i have an image in android project in drawable folder.And i downloaded it with 16x16 pixel .But if i run above code. Image didn't came 16 pixel.
How can i set height or width from image component on xamarin.forms

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this should work for you.
I think the problem lies in the VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"

What happens is since the image and label are contained in the Grid, they inherit.

Try changing the VerticalOptions on the Grid.